# Accessing array elements by deep index

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm having trouble accessing an element, its on the last leaf of a resource tree. I am having trouble iterating through the elements by an iterator though. I'd like to get the type.id of every value I have in the $scope.values array. All of them have a type.id property.

The offender in question:

```
for (var i=0; i < $scope.values.length; i++) {
    Type.getType({id:$scope.values[i].type.id}, function (results) {
         $scope.values[i].type = results;
         return results;
    });
}
```

Gives:
    TypeError: Cannot set property 'type' of undefined

The line and row for the error puts the cursor to: $scope.values[i].type = results; However I can log the results out fine and its a resource array with 2 items in it.

The two more standard methods of accessing elements work fine however, if I change them at both places.

```
$scope.values[0]
```

or

```
$scope.values["0"]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: if you provide correct error message, then error not with `$scope.values[i].type.id` somewhere else you try assign _type_ property for object that is _undefined_

Comment: Its a service in angularJS for getting objects from the backend through HTTP.

Comment: Ok, I put in what I took out. It does have an assignment.

Comment: @hardcore, methinks, you not understand what i mean :-)

Comment: can you provide screenshot browser console with error mesage?

Comment: The line and row for the error puts the cursor to:
       `$scope.values[i].type = results;`
However I can log the results out fine and its a resource array with 2 items in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't tell what Type.getType does and so I have no idea when the function you apply as second argument gets called, maybe it's a callback?. But I am pretty sure, that when this function is called, the value of i is not what you intend it to be. This is not a closure and i seems to be on global scope.

You can try it like this:

```js
for (var i=0; i < $scope.values.length; i++) {
    Type.getType({id:$scope.values[i].type.id}, function (results) {        
          var index = i;
         $scope.values[index].type = results;
         return results;
    });
}
```

Comment: You are right when logged out index is giving 2 for the first time it runs, while the length is 2, so it should be 0 and then a 1. Strangely this wasnt the case when I logged it out as I originally had it in the question.